# How install a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, repository, installation

How i can install this github repository about YouTube Music?

https://github.com/steve228uk/YouTube-Music

Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the website.
Go to read me file that is said
Scroll down until you see the hyperlink: “download the latest version”
Click on it.
No problem.